# XMLRAD / How to create a new application with the http://localhost:8000/XMLRAD/ environment

Tags: xml

Maybe it's my eyes but I don't found the bouton for the to create a new application with this tools.
I'm with a running Wampserver64, under Win7-64, and I use PHP and the rad Netbeans (with XDebug)

Thank's for your prompt come back

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDVtD.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

To create a new application with XMLRAD LTD, you will duplicate the demo Ultima, rename directory and necessary files (ie: Ultima2), and register the project (ie: Ultima2).